# prop.exe elevated execution in Wix

Tags: wix, administrator

This question seems to have been answered ad nauseam on this web site but I cannot get Wix to run an exe with Administrator rights (Windows 8.1 64-bit).

The installer I develop copies the prop.exe utility (http://prop.codeplex.com/) to a folder under Program Files (appfolder) as well as a file (my_file.propdesc) which needs to be registered/unregistered by prop.exe like:

```
prop schema register my_file.propdesc (at the end of installation)

prop schema unregister my_file (at the beginning of uninstallation)
```

These two command lines need to be run with Administrator privileges. Because these should also be run without a command prompt, I've used CAQuietExec with another CustomAction preparing the argument for CAQuietExec (prop.exe is 32-bit so it's CAQuietExec instead of CAQuietExec64 if I am not mistaken).

```
<CustomAction Id='PropReg_Prep' Property='PropReg' Value='"[appfolder]prop.exe" schema register "[appfolder]my_file.propdesc"' Execute='immediate' />
<CustomAction Id='PropUnReg_Prep' Property='PropUnReg' Value='"[appfolder]prop.exe" schema unregister "[appfolder]my_file.propdesc"' Execute='immediate' />
<CustomAction Id="PropReg" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />
<CustomAction Id="PropUnReg" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no" />
```

The custom actions are executed as per:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="PropReg_Prep" After="CostFinalize" >NOT Installed</Custom>
<Custom Action="PropUnReg_Prep" After="CostFinalize" >Installed</Custom>
<Custom Action="PropUnReg" After="InstallInitialize" >Installed</Custom>
<Custom Action="PropReg" After="InstallFiles" >NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I cannot get prop to register/unregister my_file.propdesc. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are scheduling the actions as `Execute='immediate'` this runs as the user that executes the installer.

Switch to using `Execute='deferred'` this will run as the system account. Assuming that the `prop.exe` doesn't require a full profile to run this should work.

Comment: Hi Caveman_dick, thanks for the suggestion. The two last CustomAction that trigger CaQuietExec are indeed scheduled as "deferred" (one for installation, one for uninstallation). What are "immediate" are the CustomAction preparing the command line for CaQuietExec. This is straight from the Wix documentation so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you're not impersonating you're running with the system account, that's got admin privileges but if you are expecting it to be a user account then there might be issues.

The thing that looks weird to me is that [appfolder]prop.exe for a number of reasons. It doesn't look like a proper application folder, so make sure it's correct. It also needs to be in uppercase, making it a public property, and you should mark it Secure="yes" in the property element. The issue is that it may not get properly transferred from your immediate CA into the execute sequence where it's used.

p.s. Do the install creating a verbose log so you can see how those directory vales are actually being resolved at run time.

Comment: Hi PhilDW, thanks for your input. The [appfolder] is just a placeholder in the pseudo-code I posted. Your points are well-taken.